# Gradient BGs in GTK4

Tags: css, themes, gradient, gtk4

I have been using this code for gradients in GTK3 CSS:

```
background-image: -gtk-gradient (
radial,
center center, 0,
center center, 1,
from (alpha(shade(@bg_color, 1.05), 0.925)),
to (alpha(shade(@bg_color, 0.85), 0.925)));
```

but in GTK4, with this code the BG doesn't render, and in terminal it says:

```
(gtk4-widget-factory:4546): Gtk-WARNING **: 13:30:10.541: Theme parser error: gtk.css:335:19-32: Not a valid image
```

I also tried the original CSS gradient code (`radial-gradient`), with no success.

So how do I make gradients on GTK4 CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the syntax in detail, I usually just reproduce examples that I already know, but here's an example that works.

```
background-image: linear-gradient(
     to bottom right,
     #fff 49.99%,
     #202020 50.01%
   );
```

Comment: That worked, thank you, BTW both 'linear-gradient' and 'radial-gradient' didn't work at first, that must probably be an error that I haven't even noticed